# Converting curl request to python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert the cURL command to python requests, but hitting a wall. Maybe someone will have an idea.

I was using this [site](https://curl.trillworks.com/#python) for reference and I have such a cURL command:

```
curl -F "file=@myfile.json" -H "Authorization: ApiKey xxxxxxxxxxx" -F 'scan_type=Arachni Scan' -F 'tags=test' -F 'active=true' -F 'scan_date=2018-11-15' -F 'engagement=/api/v1/engagements/1/'  -F 'eid=1' https://example.com:443/api/v1/importscan/
```

After the conversion to python, my script extract looks like this:

```
files = {
    'file': ('myfile.json', open('myfile.json', 'rb')),
    'scan_type': 'Arachni Scan',
    'tags': 'test',
    'active': 'true',
    'scan_date': '2018-11-15',
    'engagement': '/api/v1/engagements/1/',
    'eid': '1',
}

response = requests.post('https://example.com:443/api/v1/importscan/', headers=headers, files=files)
print response.text
```

Unfortunately, the cURL command succeeds, but the python request returns

```
{"error": "Request is not valid JSON."}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: (1) using `json.dumps()`, (2) using a list instead of a tuple for `'file'`, or (3) doing `open(...).read()` instead of just `open()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

response = requests.post('https://example.com:443/api/v1/importscan/', headers=headers, files=json.dumps(files))
```

Use `json.dumps` would do the trick.